# Change port in OpenShift CodeReady Containers (CRC)VM

Tags: openshift, docker-desktop

I am trying to run CRC ( CodeReady Containers ) in Mac(M1) for checking openshift local. I have Docker desktop installed and running. Due to which, CRC is not starting because of the port is already assigned

```
failed to expose port 127.0.0.1:6443 -> 192.168.127.2:6443: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: bind: address already in use
```

I want to change port for CRC VM while running. But unable to find the settings to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I quit Docker Desktop, which had the port bound, and was able to resolve the issue. I had some K8s clustering going there that conflicted. OpenShift is starting on my mac now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).